# cant access res folder after importing project

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

loaded an old project by importing it.
i am trying to create a new layout and want to import an image from the drawable.
for some reason it does not recognize the fact that i add a pic (jpeg) to the folder.
did refresh. (R.drawable.yoda);
wont recognize the yoda.jpeg

Comment: try creating a NEW proyect with existing source rather than importing it.. sometimes it helps.

Comment: not workin.... any other ideas?

Comment: other than that just to copy manually the classes to a fresh proyect.